# Not recieving props in app.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to create a simple react redux page where I want to display the data on the page. I have created it but I am having some error.

I am not able to get props at the app.js page.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the context to call `this` in a function.
There are many ways to do this, either declare your function as an arrow function, ie : 
`renderList = () => { some code }`
or bind it in the constructor :

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: i am not recieving the props in app.js..it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null